# How to find API's original location / subdomain?

Tags: api, rest

We are using a third party application on our companies website to show data to user via widgets and in regards to that we are connecting the 3rd party widget to our internal application via API. The application doesn't offer any API and it seems like it someone internally developed the API and hosted it on company subdomain.

The link that we are using on widget looks like this

https://myapi.ourcompany.com/api/WjwYPjdfgdgtje4dfgdfgdfdGPCgoXJdfgrerl5BTNq5/Get

Our website is https://ourcompany.com and it seems like the person created a subdomain and hosted the API there.

How I can access the original file of these API or their hosted location?

If the application backend is on SQL then that means someone created a connection to the database and then created an API and then Hosted it on subdomain.

As the original App vendor doesn't offer any API's.

I will be glad to provide any further details if that can help.

Comment: There's no standard for subdomains or APIs; the answer here is going to depend heavily on the specific implementation. You'll probably need to start by checking DNS to see where that subdomain is pointed. Hopefully that'll start you in the right direction.

Comment: If it's a third party service you probably can't see the source. If you self-hosted and it's open source you might.

Comment: Thank you  **ceejayoz** and **Evert**  , I agree its a custom solution and I believe I have to dig that's why was just wondering if someone can point me in any direction